# Request for tag: [recon-hud]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-creation

A new tag [recon-hud] is needed for development with the Recon Instruments heads-up display. The platform is built on Android, but the questions are very specific to the Recon SDK.

Here's a question that's tagged [Android], but is specific to Recon:

[What settings should be used in AVD to accurately simulate the Recon MOD Live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274937/what-settings-should-be-used-in-avd-to-accurately-simulate-the-recon-mod-live/)

The Recon SDK info can be found here:
http://developers.reconinstruments.com/downloads/

Comment: Are there any other questions that would need that tag? If the tag is used just from a question, it is going to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @kiamlaluno. There are hundreds of questions that need that tag, but they haven't been posted on stack overflow because the tag can't be created. It's a chicken and egg thing. Can't ask questions here about the SDK for Recon HUD because there's no tag. Can't create a tag because there's not enough questions. 

I can send you a list of development questions that could/should be posted on stack overflow.

Should I get more questions posted with the Android tag and then ask again?

Comment: You can ask a question about Recon HUD SDK; it will not have a tag like [tag:recon-hud], but the question would be about Recon HUD SDK the same.